# QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated

Tags: python, pyqt5

I get the following warning when I run the code below

```
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen DPI.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
```

code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QStackedWidget
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class WelcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def _init_(self):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self)._init_()
        loadUi("screen1.ui", self)


# main

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
welcome = WelcomeScreen()
widget = QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(welcome)
widget.setFixedHeight(500)
widget.setFixedWidth(800)
widget.show()

# app.exec_()

try:
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except:
    print("exiting")
```

Comment: It's probably deprecated because there hasn't been a device with non-square pixels in 30 years.

Comment: That is probably an environment variable set on your system, and you can ignore that.